# How to retrieve an argument in GNUmakefile

Tags: makefile

No sure if anyone knows the answer of this question, I looked around and can’t find a solution yet. I have a makefile that looks like the following:

```
    MODELS := abc def
    all:    all_models
    all_models: $(foreach m,$(MODELS),test$(m))

    test%:
        echo $(subst test,,$@)

    Output:
    echo abc
    abc
    echo def
    def
```

I know the $(m) abc and def are passed in via test%: My question is what if for some file dependency reason, I have to hardcode test%: to something like “test:” how do I retrieve the arguments, i.e abc and def? For example the new clause is like

```
    test:
        # how do I retrieve abc and def from MODELS ?
```

Thank

Comment: the official GNU make manual is about 200 pages long, including the index, you can probably read it in no time https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/

Comment: I did and found no solution. Maybe it can't be done?

Comment: What you're asking for is trivially easy. I think you have a different question in mind.

Comment: Right, sorry for not making my question clear. I meant to retrieve "abc" when test: is executed at the 1st time and "def" when test: is executed at the 2nd time, etc.

Comment: Why is `test` being run more than once in your "hardcoded" case? How does that static target get run with different dependencies in your universe?

Comment: say in test rule, I call a script with the argument such as "abc", "def"

Answer (score 0):

I still don't think you're asking for what you really want, but here goes.

In the file `models`:

```
MODELS := abc def ghi jkl
```

In the makefile:

```
include models

test:
    @echo do something with $(word 1,$(MODELS))
    @echo MODELS := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(MODELS)), $(MODELS)) > models
```